# HBase: region-regionserver assignment not even

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have just upgraded our hadoop cluster to Hadoop 2.2 + HBase 0.98. We have found some issues, the most critical one is that the regions are not evenly assigned over regionservers.

For example, I have one table which has 125 regions and it is assigned as following:

- hslave1   13
- hslave2   10
- hslave3   6
- hslave4   23
- hslave5   8
- hslave6   26
- hslave7   8
- hslave8   34

When we used the older version (0.94.7), we didn't have the same issue. What should be the parameters of configuration we need to check? Compaction? Split?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a parameter in hbase-site.xml:

`<property>
    <name>hbase.master.loadbalance.bytable</name>
    <value>true</value>
 </property>`

By default, it's false. So the balance between region servers is good, but load balance at the table level is not taken into account. Set this value to true, HBase will balance the region over region servers at the table level.

Comment: But will this be enough? I've read that you need to apply salting, defining row keys in such a way that rows of a table get into different regions. What is your experience with this?